# PyQt: How Can I set row heights of QTreeView

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, pyqt5, qtreeview

In PyQt, I am looking for a way to set the height of rows in a `QTreeView` (similarly to `QTableView.setRowHeight(row, row_height)`, but `QTreeView` does not have this function). `QAbstractItemModel` is used to set the tree model. I read some suggestions [here](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d875894/c-cpp/bibliotheques/qt/changer-hauteur-d-rangee-qtreewidget/) using and sub-classing `QAbstractItemDelegate.sizeHint(option, index)` but I don't know exactly how to call them correctly within my tree model.

Any minimal code or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `QTreeView` works out a height for each row based on the data and size hints returned for each item.  I think you probably just need to return size hints, either for all your items, or at least the first row (if you have `setUniformRowHeights(True)`).  Incidentally this can significantly improve performance and so you should set it if you can.

So you just need to implement your `AbstractItemModel.data()` method to return a size hint in the `SizeHintRole`.  Something like this:

```
def data(self, index, role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    #  Check the index, possibly return None
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        # Return the data
    elif role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
        return QtCore.QSize(item_width,item_height)
    # Other roles - maybe return None if you don't use them.
```

**EDIT:  Big example**

You say you are still having trouble so here is a complete working example, based on the standard QT itemviews example.  Try varying the QSize returned in the data method to see how the view changes:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore,QtGui

class TreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self.parentItem = parent
        self.data = data
        self.childItems = []

    def appendChild(self, item):
        self.childItems.append(item)

    def row(self):
        if self.parentItem:
            return self.parentItem.childItems.index(self)
        return 0


class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rootItem = TreeItem(None)
        for i,c in enumerate("abcdefg"):
            child = TreeItem([i,c],self.rootItem)
            self.rootItem.appendChild(child)
        parent = self.rootItem.childItems[1]
        child = TreeItem(["down","down"],parent)
        parent.appendChild(child)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            item = index.internalPointer()
            return item.data[index.column()]
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
            print "giving size hint"
            return QtCore.QSize(40,40)

        return None


    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return ["A","B"][section]
        return None

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if not parent.isValid():
            parentItem = self.rootItem
        else:
            parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        childItem = parentItem.childItems[row]
        if childItem:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        parentItem = index.internalPointer().parentItem
        if parentItem == self.rootItem:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        return self.createIndex(parentItem.row(), 0, parentItem)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0
        if not parent.isValid():
            parentItem = self.rootItem
        else:
            parentItem = parent.internalPointer()
        return len(parentItem.childItems)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = TreeModel()

    view = QtGui.QTreeView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.setWindowTitle("Simple Tree Model")
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. I implemented this but it does not work yet in my case (the condition ´elif role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole´ is never satisfied), probably because I have to set setData so that sizeHint is called (as mentionned by @RazrFalcon). I will forward the code once it works. Thanks again

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine in my example.  Calling setData is not going to work: that only applies to QStandardItemModels not QAbstractItemModel.  Can you give a stripped down version of your code that I can test?  SizeHintRole should be requested by the View when it first accesses the model.

Comment: I've added a complete example that I have tested and works fine.  If you are still having problems then there is something else wrong with your AbstractItemModel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code works like a charm! I didn't find such a simple solution on other blogs. I figure out my (stupid) mistake: I tried your solution in copy-pasted code in which there is a return None if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole. Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty simple to do this with stylesheet :

```
self.setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item { padding: 10px }")
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about Python, but C++ code would be like this:

```
model->setData(model->index(/*your index*/), QSize(20, 20), Qt::SizeHintRole);
```

And you need to set it for all items in your tree.

If you want use QItemDelegate - you no need to call this function, you just set your delegate to view, like this (C++ code again, but main idea is the same):

```
treeView->setItemDelegate(new MyDelegate(this));
```

Than view will use it when it need it.

Comment: I use the PySide bindings for Python, so I'll convert your code to Python. ||

tree = QTreeView()
tree.model = QtGui.QAbstractItemModel()
tree.setModel(tree.model)
tree.model.setData(tree.model.index(someIndex), QtCore.QSize(20, 20), QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole)

|| And... ||

delegate = MyDelegate()
tree.setItemDelegate(delegate)

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh would be helpful to just turn that into a separate answer with formatting.

Comment: Sure @neuronet, it's up in 5.

Answer (score 1):

For the PySide bindings, here's the Python code for the custom delegate on the AbstractItemModel.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

tree = QTreeView()
tree.model = QtGui.QAbstractItemModel()
tree.setModel(tree.model)

size = QtCore.QSize(20, 20)
index = tree.model.index(row, col)   # row, col are your own
tree.model.setData(index, size, QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole)

delegate = MyDelegate()
tree.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

This is just translating the code from @RazrFalcon to Python, and was requested by another user.

Answer (score 0):

With Qt 5.9.2, I had trouble with simultaneously getting QTreeView auto-sizing columns and custom row heights.  Using SizeHintRole worked for height but seemingly wrecked auto-width.  The solution for me was to set the rows to have uniform heights and then do something like this in Python 3.7:

```
self._tree = QTreeView()
self._tree.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
self._tree.setUniformRowHeights(True)

...

fi = QFontInfo(self.font())

self._tree.setStyleSheet(
    f'''
    QTreeView {{
        alternate-background-color: #E6FFFF;
    }}
    QTreeView::Item{{
        height:{fi.pixelSize() * 2}px;
    }}
    ''')
```

I'll speculate that setting colors and heights this way provides a tiny bit of a performance improvement.