# QTreeWidget - re-calculate row height per row content?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

It's a quick one. I put a QWidget with layout containing 10 buttons in each of my QTreeWidgetItem that i can expand-contract.

If i contract the QWidget(hide), the row then remains the same height. It should get resized to be a lot smaller to contain only unhide button. The space occupied by the row remains empty. Only when I add a new widget. The row's height gets re-calculated. Same goes for expanding. If I expand widget, it still is 17 pixels in height. Only when I add a new widget the row's height gets recalculated.

Is there a built-in function in QTreeWidget that I can call to update its row height - content, or do I need to loop over each item and adjust its height manually?

Also is it a good idea to put a QWidget containing layout and lots of widgets inside QTreeWidgetItem? If I want to have lets say 500 QtreeWidgetItems, each having QTreeWidget with 20  Buttons/etc items in it?

Regards
Dariusz

Edit1.

I spend quite a bit of time on it. Tried different paths but so far no luck. I have attached my rough code to show the issue. Just click on hide 1-2 times to see what happens. I'm struggling to understand how the "sizeHint" thini work...

Attached my test below.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook


def my_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    # print(exctype, value, traceback)
    sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
    sys.exit(1)


sys.excepthook = my_exception_hook


class myWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, something):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.MW = parent
        self.MWa = something
        self.lay_main = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.lay_main)

        self.le_lineA = QLineEdit()
        self.btn_a = QPushButton("Hey")
        self.btn_a.clicked.connect(self.hideunhide)
        self.subWidget = QWidget()
        self.subLay = QGridLayout()
        self.subWidget.setLayout(self.subLay)

        self.btn_b = QPushButton("Boo")
        self.lay_main.addWidget(self.btn_a)
        self.lay_main.addWidget(self.subWidget)
        self.subLay.addWidget(self.le_lineA)
        self.subLay.addWidget(self.btn_b)
        print("Im created :- )")
        self.size = False

    def hideunhide(self):
        if self.subWidget.isHidden():
            self.subWidget.show()
            self.size = True
            self.MW.sizeHint(1)
            self.MW.setSizeHint(0, QSize(0, 0))

        else:
            self.subWidget.hide()
            self.size = False
            self.MW.sizeHint(1)
            self.MW.setSizeHint(0, QSize(0, 0))


class widgetItemDictUpdate(QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent, MW, title, dicId):
        super(QTreeWidgetItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.MW = MW
        self.dicId = dicId


class myDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, mw):
        self.MW = mw
        super(QItemDelegate, self).__init__()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        print("myDelegate", option, index)
        if self.MW.itemFromIndex(index).layer.size:
            return QSize(100, 100)
        return QSize(100, 30)


class treeWidget(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, MW):
        QTreeWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setUniformRowHeights(False)
        self.MW = MW
        self.itemClicked.connect(self.printClick)
        self.setHeaderItem(QTreeWidgetItem(["Name", "ProgressBar", "extra", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]))
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.dragItems = []

        self.lastHidenItemsArray = []
        self.hiddenItemsSet = []

        self.delg = myDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(self.delg)
        self.addItems(self.invisibleRootItem())

    def printClick(self, item, column):
        print("Clicked")

    def addItems(self, parent):
        testParent = self.addSlave(parent, 'RandomA', 50)
        testParent = self.addSlave(parent, 'RandomB', 60)
        testParent = self.addSlave(parent, 'RandomBX', 60)
        testParent = self.addSlave(parent, 'RandomBcvas', 60)

    def addSlave(self, parent, title, id, expanded=True, visible=True):
        item = widgetItemDictUpdate(parent, self, title, id)
        myLayer = myWidget(item, self)
        item.setText(0, title)
        item.layer = myLayer
        self.setItemWidget(item, 1, myLayer)
        item.id = id
        item.type = 1

        return item


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.treeWidget = treeWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setGeometry(1000, 500, 500, 500)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hey @Dariusz. I had another think and looked deeper into the docs and it turns out that QTableWidgets / QTableViews have dynamic row heights built in which you can modify using the function QTableWidget::setRowHeight( int index, int height ). Are you locked into using a QTreeWidget or could you use  a QTableWidget instead?

Comment: Hey @aatwo. Started working on this issue again. Not sure if QTablewidgets will work, can I move the rows up/down/group them as with QTreeWidget? I tried some basic tests but so far no luck

Comment: So it depends on the structure of your data. If you are actually using the tree part of the QTreeViews functionality i.e. one or more rows are children of another row, then unfortunately you are pretty much locked in. I just wanted to point out their superior control over the row heights! You can definitely move rows up / down though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there is no way to resize rows directly though you can achieve a dynamic row height by implementing your table as a QTreeView + QSortFilterProxyModel subclass pair ([PyQt: How Can I set row heights of QTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229314/pyqt-how-can-i-set-row-heights-of-qtreeview))

Alternatively I imagine removing the widget from the table (removeItemWidget) and then instantly re-adding it would cause a row size recalculation though I have not tested that.

As for my opinions regarding this setup of layouts inside tables, it is worth noting two things:

- Qt layouts are slow to populate and resize.
- Qt tables with variable row heights are slow in general.

That being said 500 isn't a huge number. I would probably knock together a quick prototype and see how it performs on a range of machines to see if the performance is acceptable and then worry about exploring other routes if it is too slow. I expect performance in this case will be most dependent on how complex the layouts are.

Comment: hey @aatwo thanks for suggestion with removeItemWidget, I'm thinking about it atm. I've added an example code of my current attempt at solving the issue... new grounds.